Flask swagger is not loading - flasgger
I have used flasgger to create Swagger UI for my flask application. On local it is working fine & swagger is loading properly but when I am running it on the server I am getting below error:

**Below are my configurations: **
app.py
app = Flask(__name__)
config = Config()
app.config.from_object(config)
app.config["SWAGGER"] = {"specs_route": '/swagger'}
swagger_config = {
    "headers": [],
    "specs": [
        {
            "endpoint": 'apispec_1',
            "route": '/apispec_1.json',
            "rule_filter": lambda rule: True,  # all in
            "model_filter": lambda tag: True,  # all in
        }
    ],
    "static_url_path": "/flasgger_static",
    "swagger_ui": True,
    "specs_route": '/swagger'
}
swagger = Swagger(
    app, config=swagger_config, template_file='swagger.yaml'
)

swagger.yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: Service
  version: "1.0.0"
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json

securityDefinitions:
  bearerAuth:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: Authorization
    description: Enter the token with the Bearer prefix, e.g. "Bearer abcde12345"

paths:
  /healthcheck:
    get:
      tags:
        - Healthcheck
      responses:
        200:
          description: health check of notification module

I tried updating the Swagger or OpenAPI version swagger: "2.0" & openapi: 3.0.0, but no luck.
